# Hover info within a selection in Plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

When selecting a set of points in a plotly scatter plot, the displaying of hover data is disabled.
This behavior can very well be observed in any of the examples in the [plotly selection doc](https://plotly.com/python/selections/).

Using dash, I was able to customize the hover template easily by using a callback such as:

```
app = JupyterDash("Display")
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id="graph", figure=fig, clear_on_unhover=True),
    dcc.Tooltip(id="graph-tooltip"),
])

@app.callback(
    Output("graph-tooltip", "show"),
    Output("graph-tooltip", "bbox"),
    Output("graph-tooltip", "children"),
    Input("graph", "hoverData"),
)
def display_hover(hoverData):
    # extract hovered-on point information from hoverData and return the templated data as html elements.
    pass
```

After selecting a set of points, for example using lasso selection, hovering over any of the points inside the lasso will fail to trigger this callback, although any points outside will succeed. This probably because the "lasso component" now sits on top of my original plot.

I was not able to find out how to get a callback on the selected points. Any leads or examples on how I could pass-through the selection and trigger the hover callback? Or am I thinking about this issue the wrong way?